# iOS 11 backBarButtonItem repeat

Tags: navigationbar, ios11

[image: 1]

It was working fine until we tested our application in iOS 11.

```
UIImage* imageNor = [UIImage imageNamed:@"nav_icon_back_nor1"];
UIImage* imagePre = [UIImage imageNamed:@"nav_icon_back_pre1"];
UIBarButtonItem *item = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] init];
[item setBackButtonBackgroundImage:[imageNor resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0,imageNor.size.width, 0, 0)] forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[item setBackButtonBackgroundImage:[imagePre resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0,imagePre.size.width, 0, 0)] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[item setBackButtonTitlePositionAdjustment:UIOffsetMake(-400.f, 0) forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[item setTitle:@""];
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = item;
```

Comment: Please post your code as text not image.

Comment: Provide constraint to bar button item. From iOS11, navigation bar button items playing with constraint instead of frames